# ElasticSearch deep learning

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch index which logs my scraper statistics, like response status and headers used. How to do something like machine learning to generate a guess which combination of headers would succeed the best in future scrapes. is it possible to do with plain Elasticsearch if not - what plugins would you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I found out ELK only provides machine learning functionalities in Kibana's X-Pack extension, e.g. anomaly detection and forecasts [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/ml-gs-forecast.html). For me it's useless because my model would need advanced data filtering and I want to visualize all my predictions on a dashboard. If you want to make custom predictions then the only way is to make your own script for predictions or use some out of the box ML solution like for example  [Amazon Machine Learning](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/).

You can treat Elasticsearch as an ordinary NoSQL database and periodically extract raw data from Elasticsearch using REST requests and redirect it to a created ML script or ML webservice. Then you can save predictions to Elasticsearch as a new index which can be later visualized in Kibana.

```
               HTTP GET                                     HTTP PUT
Elasticsearch =========> Script(Filtering and Predictions) ==========> Elasticsearch
```

I'm still looking for the best solution to produce predictions but for now custom script seems like the only option and I'm currently developing it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "advanced data filtering"?